# TicTacToe.java issues with checkWinner method

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I created a checkWinner method, using 'row' and 'col' private variables so I can locate the 'curPlayer' position in the 2D array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacBoard
{
  private char[][] board;  // 2-D array of characters
  private char curPlayer; // the player whose turn it is (X or O)
  // added so I can locate the current player location in the board
  private int row;
  private int col;

  // Constructor: board will be size x size
  public TicTacBoard(int size)
  {
    board = new char[size][size];

    // initialize the board with all spaces:
    for(row=0; row < board.length; row++)
      for(col=0; col < board[row].length; col++)
        board[row][col] = ' ';

    curPlayer = 'X';  // X gets the first move
  }

  public void playGame()
  {
    display();
    do
    {
      takeTurn();
      display();
    }while(!checkWinner(row, col));
  }

  ///////  display  ////////
  // Display the current status of the board on the
  // screen, using hyphens (-) for horizontal lines
  // and pipes (|) for vertical lines.
  public void display()
  {
    System.out.println();
    dispRow(0);
    System.out.println("-----");
    dispRow(1);
    System.out.println("-----");
    dispRow(2);
    System.out.println();
  }

  // Display the current status of row r of the board
  // on the screen, using hyphens (-) for horizontal
  // lines and pipes (|) for vertical lines.
  private void dispRow(int r)
  {
    System.out.println(board[r][0] + "|" + board[r][1]
                       + "|" + board[r][2]);
  }

  ///////  takeTurn  ////////
  // Allow the curPlayer to take a turn.
  // Send output to screen saying whose turn
  // it is and specifying the format for input.
  // Read user's input and verify that it is a
  // valid move.  If it's invalid, make them
  // re-enter it.  When a valid move is entered,
  // put it on the board.
  public void takeTurn()
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row, col;
    boolean invalid;

    do{
      invalid = false; // assume correct entry
      System.out.println("It is now " + curPlayer + "'s turn.");
      System.out.println("Please enter your move in the form row column.");
      System.out.println("So 0 0 would be the top left, and 0 2 would be the top right.");
      row = scan.nextInt();
      col = scan.nextInt();

      if(row < 0 || col < 0 || row > 2 || col > 2)
      {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry: row and column must both be between 0 and 2 (inclusive).");
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
        invalid = true;
      }
      else if(board[row][col] != ' ')
      {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry: Row " + row + " at Column " + col
                           + " already contains: " + board[row][col]);
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
        invalid = true;
      }
    }while(invalid);
    // Now that input validation loop is finished, put the move on the board:
    board[row][col] = curPlayer;

    // Switch to the other player (take turns):
    if(curPlayer == 'X')
      curPlayer = 'O';
    else
      curPlayer = 'X';
  }

  // If the game is over, print who won (if anyone),
  // and return true.  If the game is not over, return false.
  public boolean checkWinner(int row, int col)
  {
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
    int x = row;
    int y = col;
    // board length is always 3 here
    // check winner on column
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      if (board[x][i] != curPlayer)
        break;
      if (i == board.length - 1)
        System.out.println("Player " + curPlayer + " wins!");
        return true;
    }
    
    //check winner on row
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      if (board[i][y] != curPlayer)
        break;
      if (i == board.length - 1)
        System.out.println("Player " + curPlayer + " wins!");
        return true;
    }

    // checks winner on diagonal up 
    if (x == y) {
      for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i][i] != curPlayer)
          break;
        if (i == board.length - 1)
          System.out.println("Player " + curPlayer + " wins!");
          return true; 
      }
    }

    // check winner on diagonal down
    if (x + y == board.length - 1){
      for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i][(board.length-1)-i] != curPlayer)
          break;
        if (i == board.length - 1)
          System.out.println("Player " + curPlayer + " wins!");
        return true;
      }
    }

    // checks if board is full
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == '-')
          System.out.println("Nobody won, game ends in a draw!");
          return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

The code works but I while I was checking I got this:

```
 | | 
-----
 | | 
-----
 | | 

It is now X's turn.
Please enter your move in the form row column.
So 0 0 would be the top left, and 0 2 would be the top right.
2 0

 | | 
-----
 | | 
-----
X| | 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at TicTacBoard.checkWinner(TicTacBoard.java:126)
    at TicTacBoard.playGame(TicTacBoard.java:43)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

I thought the board length is always 3 with the location ranging from 0 to 3. Any solutions to this error? Any more efficient ways to do this? Please let me know!

Comment: Beware of `Scanner#nextInt`, this is going to leave a dandling new line character in the buffer, which does cause problems

Comment: Array length of 3 means 3 possible values having indices 0, 1, 2. So there is no index 3 in array of length 3.

Comment: You are passing `3` as the `row` value - don't know why yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "shadowing" problem - that is, you're shadowing the instance fields `row` and `col` with local variables in your `takeTurn` method.

In it's current state...

```
// Constructor: board will be size x size
public TicTacBoard(int size) {
    board = new char[size][size];

    // initialize the board with all spaces:
    for (row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            board[row][col] = ' ';
        }
    }

    curPlayer = 'X';  // X gets the first move
}
```

after the constructor has run, `row` and `col` will be `3`, but in `takeTurn`, you define `row` and `col` as local variables...

```
public void takeTurn() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row, col;
    boolean invalid;
```

This means, that when you call `checkWinner` in the `playGame` method...

```
public void playGame() {
    display();
    do {
        takeTurn();
        display();
    } while (!checkWinner(row, col));
}
```

You're passing the instance field values (of `3`/`3`) and everything breaks.

So, the "quick" solution would be to remove the local declaration of `row`/`col` from `takeTurn`

```
public void takeTurn() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int row, col;
    boolean invalid;
```

You could also fix this in the constructor, but making `row`/`col` local variables

```
for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
        board[row][col] = ' ';
    }
}
```

but at some point, you need to update the `row`/`col` value for the player, but I might consider passing this information back from `takeTurn` rather than trying to use instance fields.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a subtle, but common bug in your `if` statements.  Without **brackets**, `{` and `}`, only the line IMMEDIATELY following the `if` statement will be executed when the conditional statement above is true. Your INDENTATION, however, indicates that you expected a different behavior.

For instance, your very first `for` loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  if (board[x][i] != curPlayer)
    break;
  if (i == board.length - 1)
    System.out.println("Player " + curPlayer + " wins!");
    return true;
}
```

Here, only the `System.out.println()` line is executed when the `if` statement is true.  The indentation of the `return true;` statement indicates that you expect it to only run with the `println()`, only when the conditional is true.

The `return true;` line is NOT dependent upon the preceding `if` statement, though, because it is not within brackets and the `if` statement only runs the line immediately following it. This means that the `for` loop is only ever running ONE ITERATION because the `return` line is STAND-ALONE and executes every single time, regardless of how those `if` statements evaluate.

You should ALWAYS, ALWAYS, ALWAYS add brackets to your `if` statements, even if they are "one-liners".  With that in mind, I'd expect it to look more like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
  if (board[x][i] != curPlayer) {
    break;
  }
  if (i == board.length - 1) {
    System.out.println("Player " + curPlayer + " wins!");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now the `return` line is only executed when the preceding `if` statement is true.